# Bootstrap: clip image without resizing and stay within container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[this is my first post - please be gentle ;-) ]

I have an image I'm trying to use as part of a page header.  The image is (intentionally) very wide, so it can be used on any device width.

Part of the image is just a (patterned) long line (looks a bit like a string or rope), which can cropped (from the right) as needed.

As the device width changes, I would like the image to *not* change scale, but rather to clip the end of the string, so that the visible width of the image follows the width that Bootstrap sets for the body.

Another way to put it:  I still want the container to resize and be responsive as the device width changes, however I don't want the image to re-scale, I want it to crop the rightmost part of the image to the bounds of its parent container instead.

I have something like this in the HTML:

```
<body class="container>
  <header class="row-fluid">
    <div class="my-image-container">
      <img class="my-image" src="images/my_image.png" alt="" />
    </div>
  </header>
  ...
</body>
```

And CSS:

```
.my-image-container {
  /* What to put here? */
}

.my-image {
  /* What to put here? */
}
```

I tried using the following:

```
.my-image {
  max-width: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

However, while it no longer resized the image, the end of the image would run to the edge of the browser when I resized it, instead of keeping it bound to the confines of the body/header/div parents' width.

There were other questions/answers here and there that seemed to use relative/absolute positions in the container and image (respectively), along with a few other settings, however I didn't have much luck with that either.

I also tried breaking up the image into a smaller segment that I could repeat, but the resulting output was not aesthetically pleasing.

I have not been able to find any prior questions that address this particular problem, and I'm hoping you can help me.

Appreciate your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a background image would be an easier way to go about things, and gives you the option later to add text etc on top, which is fairly standard for headers :)

Welcome to Stack Overflow, may everyone else be gentle (good luck!)

```css
.my-image-container {
  height: 250px;
  background: url("http://placehold.it/800x250") top left no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<header class="row-fluid">
  <div class="my-image-container"></div>
</header>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm on the first attempt.  Many thanks for the prompt reply (and the warm welcome).

Comment: That's great, onwards and upwards